# How can I run two Python scripts at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried for a good two hours to get an answer to this, but nothing has helped yet. I'm running two python scripts that will work at the same time. I've seen people be told to use

```
python3 script.py & script1.py
```

but that only seems to run the first script named.

Edit:

You may run multiple files like this:

```
python3 script.py && script1.py
```

Or, you may use [honcho](https://pypi.org/project/honcho):

- Install honcho:

  ```
  pip3 install honcho
  ```
- Create procfile:

(create file named "Procfile")

- Open "Procfile", and type the following:

  ```
  script: python3 script.py 
  script1: python3 script1.py
  ```
- Run the code

  ```
  honcho start
  ```

Comment: Run them in separate terminate with `python3 script.py` and `python3 script1.py`

Comment: Separate them with a `;`, e.g. `python3 script.py; python3 script1.py`. See more here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159493

Comment: @Ahmad as your link notes, that runs them _sequentially_, not at the same time.

Comment: There are different ways to do this for different shells. Into what shell are you typing this command?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/269434/748131), chaining commands once they're backgrounded using an ampersand is free in bash.

So `python script1.py & python script2.py &` should work for you.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat script1.py 
import time
start = time.time()
time.sleep(5)
print(f"Finished#1 in {time.time() - start:.1f} seconds")
$ cat script2.py 
import time
start = time.time()
time.sleep(3)
$ python3 script1.py & python3 script2.py &
[1] 1490
[2] 1491
$ Finished#2 in 3.0 seconds
Finished#1 in 5.0 seconds
```